# Would keeping a silver dollar inside a full Camelbak prevent mold/bacteria growth?

Tags: water-purification, drinking-water

When you're out and about in the wilderness for some time (say, a week), it might be difficult to keep your Camelbak clean and free from bacteria/mold. Sure, I can regularly drop water purifying tablets into water, but they taste yucky...

My grandma used to keep a silver spoon inside a water jug *"to keep water from going bad"*.
If I put a silver dollar inside a Camelbak, would that help or is this an old-*[grand]*-wives-tale?..

Comment: How do you keep your water bottle when you are *not* using it? Inverted, without the stopper in place, and in a dry environment?

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, and in a freezer.

Answer (score 1):

Silver apparently has an antibacterial affect under certain conditions. Another possible origin of the idea is dinnerware made of German Silver. German silver is a bass with addition of several per-cent nickel to make the color silver. The copper in the alloy would inhibit bacteria; copper metal and compounds are commonly used to inhibit bacteria, etc.

Comment: Silver dollars in milk containers were used, whether they worked or not. Nano silver particles are used on fabrics these days to reduce body odor.

Comment: Silver really does have an antibacterial effect. "The antibacterial activity of silver has long been known and has found a variety of applications because its toxicity to human cells is considerably lower than to bacteria." https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18476264/

Comment: The NIH article seems mostly to refer to silver ion as might result from adding silver nitrate to water; but I will change my answer.